# How to match, count and replace string with spaces but which are not substring of another alphabetic string?

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

I have to get the total count of a particular `string` `s1` inside another `string` `s2`. Where `s1` can contain spaces. But I have to make sure the `s1` either standalone, or it is a sub-string with `emoji`, `emoticon` or `symbol`. But not a sub-string with any `alphabetic` character. Following are some examples:

Say we want to match a string `bad word`:

Following are the cases where it should be matched:

```
bad word
This is a bad word.
This are bad word bad word.
This is a bad word also.
This are bad word bad word as well.
bad word:(
bad word
bad word bad word
```

etc.

Following are the cases where we should not match it:

```
This isbad word
bad wordsdsdsd
bad wordbad word
```

etc.

That is `bad word` should be matched when it is standalone or as a sub-string with any `emoticon` or `emoji` but not as a sub-string with any `alphabetic` character.

Please note that, alphabet can be from other languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to match on `\bbad word\b`, with word boundaries around the text:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

inp = ['bad word', 'This is a bad word.', 'This is a bad word also.', 'bad word:(', 'bad word', 'This isbad word', 'bad wordsdsdsd']
for w in inp:
    if re.search(r'\bbad word\b', w):
        print("MATCH: " + w)
    else:
        print("NO MATCH: " + w)
```

This prints:

```
MATCH: bad word
MATCH: This is a bad word.
MATCH: This is a bad word also.
MATCH: bad word:(
MATCH: bad word
NO MATCH: This isbad word
NO MATCH: bad wordsdsdsd
```

Comment: For some input `inp`, use: `len(re.findall(r'\bbad word\b', inp))` ... the sample data you gave only contain single matches.

Comment: question updated. And I need to replace it as well, because if for some input it is `These are bad bad word` and we are finding both of `bad` and `bad word` individually, then, two of them should be matched (I am handling this case myself, first matching the larger one and replacing it). So, after matching `bad word` the count is `1` and the input will be `This are bad ` and after that when we will match `bad`, the count will be `2` and the input will be `These are ` (after replacement).

Comment: My comment above shows you how to get the counts.  I won't update my answer because your new sample data only has positive cases, so it doesn't get the point across as well as what I have above.

Comment: @hafiz031 But [here is a demo](https://rextester.com/HMGJ98196) with your updated data, if you want to see it.

Comment: For Non-English text `re.findall(r'\bকথা\b', "কথা")` is returning `[]` where it should have a match, but `re.findall(r'\bকথা\b', "কথাa")` is returning `['কথা']` where it should not have matched anything.

Comment: For non English use this version: `re.findall(r'(?<!\S)কথা(?!\S)', "কথা")` ... by the way, this is not what you asked above nor what was answered.  I strongly suggest that you stop changing your question.